# Possible for top level (App.vue) async setup?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Is it possible to use `await` in the App.vue top component?

Whenever I try and use it, the app displays nothing?

```html
<template>
    <Suspense>
        <template #default>
            <div>Hello</div>
        </template>
        <template #fallback>
            <div>Loading...</div>
        </template>
    </Suspense>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, onErrorCaptured, ref, Ref } from 'vue';
export default defineComponent({
    name: 'App',
    components: {},
    async setup() {
        console.log('async setup - App.vue');

        const error: Ref<undefined | Error> = ref(undefined);
        onErrorCaptured((e) => {
            error.value = e;
            return true;
        });
        if (error.value) return { error };

        return {};
    }
});
</script>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand what is **async** about your app component judging from what you've provided but I'll share with you what I did, for my special need.

I have a module for application settings that exports a "load application settings" function.
I wanted this object of appSettings to save state for things like: "is the side menu open or closed?"
my module also exports 2 more function, one for providing getters and setters and one to inject it all. it's like a store without the store I guess.

So in order to load the data (from IndexedDB) before the creation of the app i've modified *main.js* like so:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { loadApplicationSettings } from '@/composables/useApplicationSettings';
    loadApplicationSettings()
        .then(() => {
            const app = createApp(App)
            app.mount('#app')
        });
```

now i've loaded some data into my module, and I can now use it in *App.vue* without the need to **async** *App.vue*, since that data is now stored in the module.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { initApplicationSettings } from '@/composables/useApplicationSettings';
initApplicationSettings();
</script>
```

so basically, in order to overcome 'App.vue can't do asnyc' I just get everything ready before I use **createApp**

hope this helps.

Comment: You should provide another example where the loading of the app state is actually from a pinia store, with reactive properties

Answer (score 1):

When the `setup()` is `async`, the component itself becomes an *async component*. The component then must be rendered inside a `<suspense>` **in the parent component**. The `<suspense>` should not be in the async component's own template unless it has its own async component children.

```html
<!-- Parent.vue -->
<template>
  <Suspense>
    <template #default>
      <MyAsyncComponent />
    </template>
    <template #fallback>
      <div>Loading...</div>
    </template>
  </Suspense>
</template>
```

```html
<!-- MyAsynComponent.vue -->
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  async setup() {
    ⋮
  }
})
</script>
```

If you did not intend to make the component async, and you only had `async` code to run in `setup()`, you should wrap that code in its own `async` block (e.g., in an `async` function). For example, it's common to fetch data upon mounting the component, so you could use an `async` callback to `await` the fetch call:

```html
<!-- MyAsyncComponent -->
<script>
import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const getPosts = async () => axios.get(⋯)
    const posts = ref([])

    onMounted(async () => {
      posts.value = await getPosts()
    })

    return { posts }
  }
})
</script>
```